# Tomcat7 & Struts1 - handling multitude of Google Bot hits

Tags: tomcat, struts, scalability, google-crawlers

More than half of the hits on one of my servers are from the Google Bot, constantly crawling our millions of pages.

The reason we have so many pages is that the company is an auto parts store, with unique URLs for every combination of manufacturer part number and the vehicles it fits.  This isn't something we can get rid of; people search on these terms all the time, and we need unique landing pages for each one (because all of our competitors have them, of course!).

Thus, we have millions of pages that Google needs to know about.  That means we're getting several hits per second from their crawler, round the clock, and this is traffic that's as vital and necessary as any end-user traffic.

Because we're constantly adding new products to the catalogue, on the order of hundreds of thousands per week, our list of unique URLs grows ever longer, and the traffic has been steadily increasing.

The Google bot doesn't pay any attention to cookies, which means it gets a new session every time, so this shoots up our memory usage to the maximum allocated.

How are others with Tomcat7 and Struts dealing with such massive automated traffic?

The method I plan to try is to invalidate the session at the end of each request, in the page footer JSP tile (if and only if the user agent string is the Google crawler).  Is this an effective technique in saving memory?

What other strategies could help us handle bot traffic more effectively?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly in the field, but have you tried to take a look at:
http://www.robotstxt.org/

I guess it is a standard to which google should adhere.

Comment: The question isn't how to limit the crawler, but how to make the server handle the requests more efficiently.

Comment: well it coul help reducing the frequency of the calls from the robot, say once per second (or less) could be the right tradeoff

Comment: I don't think the issue is request volume, but the fact that each request spawns a new session.  OP has millions of pages to be crawled, with hundreds of thousands more each week.

Comment: Right - we *want* the google crawler to hit us, because getting those pages listed is extremely important for this business.  I'm just looking for strategies to handle such hits more effectively; discarding the session immediately is one such that I intend to pursue, and was wondering how well that worked, and what else is effective.